# Relating set Complement and statement Negation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

$$\{x\in X \mid \exists V{\subseteq} E\;\; V{\in} \mathscr N(x)\} \tag{1}$$
$$\{x\in E \mid \exists V{\subseteq} E\;\; V{\in} \mathscr N(x)\} \tag{2}$$
These two sets are equal to $E°.$

I know that the correct negation of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are
$$  \{x\in X \mid \forall V, V\cap E^c \neq \emptyset, V{\in} \mathscr N(x)\} \tag{3},$$ which is is correct, and
$$  \{x\in E \mid \forall V, V\cap E^c \neq \emptyset, V{\in} \mathscr N(x)\} \tag{4},$$ which isn't correct (the complement of $E°$ cannot be made elements of $E$).

What is the coherent rule to apply when taking $x$ not belonging to these sets? What is the *systematic* rule to apply to $(1)$ to obtain $(3)?$ I know that `∃` becomes `∀`, etc, but what about `x∈X`? It that seems we have not changed this part.

Comment: I can't follow your statements. Are you sure they are correctly worded?

Comment: Your (1) and (2) are incomplete. I suspect there is a critical piece missing after $\exists V\subseteq E$.

Comment: @Arthur I don't see what is the critical piece missing after $\exists V \subseteq E$ ($V$ is a neighborhood of $x$).

Comment: @niobium "$V$ is a neighbourhood of $x$" **is** the critical piece that's missing.

Comment: Yes I should have specified it. It's just that I am so used to take the letter $V$ for "neighborhood of $x$" that I forgot.

Comment: @niobium It is common. It doesn't mean you can omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(x)$ be a propositional function of $x,$ for example, $\exists k{\in}\mathbb Z\:\,x=7k.$

Then the **complement** of the set $$\left\{x\in A\mid P(x)\right\}$$ is
$$\left\{x\in A \mid P(x)\right\}^\complement\\
=\left\{x\mid x\in A\quad\textit{and}\quad P(x)\right\}^\complement\\
=\left\{x\mid \textit{not}\;\big(x\in A\quad\textit{and}\quad P(x)\big)\right\}\\
=\left\{x\mid \big(x\not\in A\quad\textit{or}\quad \textit{not}\;P(x)\big)\right\}\\
=A^\complement\cup\left\{x\mid  \textit{not}\;P(x) \right\}.
$$

P.S. We negate propositions and propositional functions, and we take complement of sets.

P.P.S. The **negation** of a tautology is a contradiction; on the other hand, the **complement** of the set of tautologies contains contingent sentences as well as contradictions.